# Hide Stack Trace in Exception Response in PHP/Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-amf

I'm wondering if there is a way to hide the stack trace in an Exception in PHP. I'm running a Zend Amf Server under ZF and would like to handle the faults on the front-end but showing the stack trace (faultDetail) isn't something I want to come across the line.

My next step is to over ride these faults and send my own object back, but I would rather over ride an Exception to just not show the trace.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is part of your ErrorController.php and `/views/scripts/error` view scripts. Most people forget that they have created it once and can do with it whatever they please.

Also note that you usually use environments in ZF. With APPLICATION_ENV you can use them to show or hide events depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own exception handler function which will do whatever you wish:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite `error.phtml` which, by default, is at `application\views\scripts\error\error.phtml` to show whatever messages you want.

Look at `application/controllors/ErrorController.php` to see how uncaught exceptions are handled.